# Where can I find Material Safety Data Sheets (MSDS's)?

Tags: safety

Are there government websites where I can view MSDS's? Or do I need to go to the manufacturer's website or make a request to the manufacturer for the MSDS's?

Comment: Google usually doesn't fail me: ["WD40 MSDS"](https://www.google.com/search?q=wd40+msds&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Comment: @Mazura. That works great unless you buy in bulk a lot, then it can be part of the PO as a mandatory request.

Comment: Start by looking for SDS instead, MSDS is obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

Material Safety Data Sheets (MSDS) and Certificate of Compliance (CoC) have to come from the manufacturer or main supplier of the product. I have worked at a few places that demanded at least a CoC, and sometimes a MSDS which was usually for hazardous chemicals. Much of this is done only once  per product, unless there is a product revision. A MSDS and/or CoC maybe included with each Purchase Order (PO).
 There usually is no charge for these sheets, which total maybe one or two sheets each at most. They are needed by the manufacturer of products that use these materials and need proof of contents and quality. The MSDS is more detailed because it often has to list the ingredients and temperature limits, flash point, freeze point, etc.
 *They also act also as a path from the end user who buys the final product back to the original source of the material*. If a non-flammable paint catch's fire and is not supposed to, then these MSDS and CoC sheets put the burden of the problem back on the original product manufacturer or main distributor, not the final assembly plant or the consumer level distributor.

Comment: @Luke1018 MSDS what changed to SDS in July 2016. So if you are looking at an Msds, then it's old, and probably not the most recent info.